# Ubuntu Live CD refuses to start up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

So I burned ubuntu 16.04 on a live CD.

I have a UEFI motherboard, when I booted Ubuntu, it shows the loading screen, then it goes black, not responding at all.

I tried a Linux Mint disc, and it just worked fine. But Ubuntu Live CD just refuses to boot up.

What I did so far:

- Turned Fast Boot Off
- Turned Fast Startup off in Windows.
- Turned Secure Boot off.
- Turned iGPU off. (I run two monitors, one in the GPU and one in the iGPU)

System specs if needed:

core i3 4130
8 GB of RAM
GTX 750 Ti
Gigabyte GA-H81M-HD3